# Spring boot integrationTest web configuration

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot, configuration

Trying implement integration test for httpClient.
HttpClient can use stub rest controller service to send data for "other web".

Configuration is:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {
     SpringMvcApplicationConfiguration.class
    , StorageConfiguration.class
    , …
})
@WebIntegrationTest({"server.port=8080", "management.port=0"})
@Transactional
public class HttpSendHelperTest {
  private final static Logger LOGGER =     LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpSendHelperTest.class);

  @Inject
  private HttpSendHelper httpSendHelper;
  @Inject
  private RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping;
…
}
```

Test starts correctly loading all my configured contests.
Checking **mapping.getHandlerMethods()** - all uris present in map.

Sending test request to default url - response status is 200,
but sending to others (trying some from mapped uris) - response status is 404.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();


restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/",
    StubBuilder.getInspection(), String.class)

responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/stub/send",
    StubBuilder.getInspection(), String.class);
```

Please suggest how to solve the problem.

Comment: Little bit more details.


_Java 7._

_Maven_ based build.

 
The web application based on spring **@Configuration**.

It does not have web.xml it is not based on Spring boot.

Web container configured using class that **implements WebApplicationInitializer**.

Application starts if war deployed to target web container.
Integration test needs embedded server.

Embedded server configured like it was described before, but it does not use _RequestMappingHandlerMapping-object_ created by spring, so Rest services can’t be used by TestRestTemplate. 
But I need rest services in my test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

It needs to configure springBoot in correct way.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebIntegrationTest({"server.port=8080", "management.port=0"})
@Transactional
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SpringBootApplicationForTest.class)
public class HttpSendHelperTest {
```

adding **SpringBootApplicationForTest.class**

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value =
                                   {
                                       StorageConfiguration.class
                                   }
)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class
    , VelocityAutoConfiguration.class
})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {
    "my.entities.path"
})
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApplicationForTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplicationForTest.class, args);
  }

}
```

**Great thanks for Petri Kainulainen (helpful advices).**